# How do I copy and paste with Kitty?

Tags: terminal, clipboard, kitty

[Kitty](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/) is a terminal for Linux. How do I copy and paste with it. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> does not work? And there is no option on right click. Right-click also doesn't work for copy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Kitty

You need to use a capital `C`. To copy and paste in

1. Select text
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. Paste with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd> in any app.

There is no method to copy with the cursor.

## Vim

Because things like VIM keep coming up. If you have Neovim installed (which is basically better vim). You can easily copy to your Xorg/Wayland buffer by selecting into the `+` buffer with `"+y`. This has the advantage of skipping over things that should not be copied, like hints,

Comment: Is there a way to set/get clipboard data by command in the console (e.g. shell script)?

Comment: @MrCalvin Yes, try `xclip`

Comment: Also, TIL: `kitty +kitten clipboard`

Comment: Try to paste with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`V`. It works for me

Comment: When I select text by dragging, it becomes immediately unselected. I have to hold Shift while dragging for some reason.

Comment: I can also paste with `CTRL`+`V`

Comment: If you're trying to copy from vim launched in an SSH session, selecting with mouse drag will enter visual mode - so CTRL+SHIFT+C won't have any effect, because you're selecting in vim, not kitty. To select in kitty, use SHIFT+left mouse button drag

Comment: @walnut_salami I updated with a note about neovim.

Comment: In vim, one solution is to create a shortcut to a custom command in vim to redirect the current selection to the kitty clipboard kitten.

`vnoremap <leader>y :w ! kitty +kitten clipboard<CR><CR>`
`nnoremap <leader>y <S-V>:w ! kitty +kitten clipboard<CR><CR>`

Answer (score 9):

We can also configure the feature `copy on select` which will copy selected text into clipboard without pressing a shortcut:

```
copy_on_select yes
```

To paste the text from clipboard, you can use the middle mouse click or set up the shortcut you want, for example:

```
map cmd+c        copy_to_clipboard
map cmd+v        paste_from_clipboard
map shift+insert paste_from_clipboard
```

Answer (score 3):

From the comments in Kitty's default configurations:

```
#::  There is also a copy_or_interrupt action that can be optionally
#::  mapped to Ctrl+c. It will copy only if there is a selection and
#::  send an interrupt otherwise. Similarly,
#::  copy_and_clear_or_interrupt will copy and clear the selection or
```

This does what I need:

```
map ctrl+c copy_and_clear_or_interrupt
map ctrl+v paste_from_clipboard
```

Comment: This is perfect. This should be the default setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the keyboard shortcuts.

To make <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> copy, you would put this in your `kitty.conf`:

```
map ctrl+c        copy_to_clipboard
```

Answer (score 1):

As for Kitty 0.28.1-2 now, you may use scrollback mode, like tmux's copy mode, with a default keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>. The mode will read the whole context of the current tty with a default pager `less`, then you can copy whatever you like, if you know how to copy text in the pager. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> read the last shell output with the pager.

You may set `scrollback_pager` as your favourite pager in config too, like a powerful `page` which can take Neovim's advantages even.

Answer (score 0):

Also note this very nice Kitten plug-in https://github.com/yurikhan/kitty_grab  that lets you copy with the keyboard.

Answer (score -2):

[The accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/500072/80216#500073) says:

> You need to use a capital `C`. To copy and paste in
>
> 1. Select text
> 2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
> 3. Paste with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> in any app.
>
> There is no method to copy with the cursor.

Right and wrong, there is a method for the mouse. 
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+RightMouseClick works also to paste.

Comment: and what that method to copy with the mouse would be?